# CSV dataset to grayscale image for processing in CNN

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, keras, dataset

I'm relatively new to all of this, so bear with me if this is a stupid question.

I have two datasets (one train, one test). I recently wrote some code to split them. I now need to convert the datasets in CSV format to grayscale images so I can start to build my model and train the neural net.

I have this code below, which uses matplotlib. The problem is the returned image shows axis and labels. The code goes through the dataset and saves each row except the first, which is the column headers. I am not sure what a better method would be to produce a grayscale image without the axis or labels. I would like to save each row one by one as I am already doing in the loop but is there any way of having the filename saved as what appears in the 'Name' column in the dataset. The full, not split, dataset can be found here:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqFNg8FC48SSgtZSObDmmGHs3utWog

The code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from keras.preprocessing.image import array_to_img
from numpy import genfromtxt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_path = "*path_to_data_train_or_test.csv*"

data = pd.read_csv(data_path);

label = data.Malware.values

data = data.drop("Malware", axis=1)
data = data.drop("Name", axis=1)
data = data.values
data = data.reshape(data.shape[0], data.shape[1], 1)
data = np.tile(data, (1, data.shape[1]))

for i in range(data.shape[0]):
plt.imshow(data[i], cmap="gray")
plt.title("label: {0:}".format(label[1]))
plt.savefig(f"output_image_.png")
plt.savefig(f"output_image_{i}.png")
plt.close()

print(data[0].shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to produce an image, you can save the array directly as an image using PIL. Just transform whatever data or row you want into an array, and pass that array to create the image data object. I used this library a lot for my DSP labs. Pseudo code because I'm not quite sure what's going on with your for loop;

```
from PIL import Image as im
data_arr = df.to_numpy()
data_image = im.fromarray()
data_image.save('/path/to/save.jpg')
```

Comment: Hi @boskosnitch. That's great but I want it as a grayscale image. Is there any way to change it to grayscale by perhaps adding a color/colour inside the im.fromarray?

Comment: You would modify the array before creating the I'm object. What does your image data look like?

Comment: The dataset I am using is attached as a link to the OneDrive folder its saved in. I am converting each of those rows.